# Trying to solve an equation

Tags: r

My problem is the following: I try to calculate a parameter (here called "`seuil`") from a survey with R, which is solution of an equation. The solution can not be explicit, but I know that it is defined.

I wrote this program

```
d<-Base_SP_final

f<-function(x) abs(-(1-d$shortA1-d$middleA1)*((d$timeA1)^(1+x))-d$shortA1*((d$timeA1+d$minshort1)^(1+x))-d$middleA1*((d$timeA1+d$minmiddle1)^(1+x))+(1-d$shortB1-d$middleB1)*((d$timeB1)^(1+x))+d$shortB1*((d$timeB1+d$minshort1)^(1+x))+d$middleB1*((d$timeB1+d$minmiddle1)^(1+x)))

d$seuil<-optimize(f, c(-10000, 10000), maximum=FALSE, tol=0.0001)
```

I have this error message: `"invalid function value in 'optimize'"`. Is it due to the fact that I use variables and not values directly ("`seuil`" has to be computed 8016 times!)?

I also tried to use `nlm` and `uniroot`, without success.

Comment: your function must return a scalar (i.e. a single value) and not a vector.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to compute the 8016 values together, to have the 8016 values in the vector d$seuil? (otherwise it will take a very long time..!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following will get you what you are after.

This writes a functions that does a single `optimize`.  You may then pass that function to `mapply` to iterate over all of your input values.

```
optim_f <- function(x, shortA1, middleA1, timeA1,
                    minshort1, minmiddle1, 
                    shortB1, middleB1, timeB1, ...){
  optimize(
    function(x, shortA1, middleA1, timeA1,
             minshort1, minmiddle1, 
             shortB1, middleB1, timeB1){
      abs(-(1 - shortA1 - middleA1) * 
            ((timeA1) ^ (1 + x)) - 
            shortA1 * 
            ((timeA1 + minshort1) ^ (1 + x)) - 
            middleA1 * 
            ((timeA1 + minmiddle1) ^ (1 + x)) + 
            (1 - shortB1 - middleB1) * 
            ((timeB1)^(1+x)) + 
            shortB1 * 
            ((timeB1 + minshort1) ^ (1 + x)) + 
            middleB1 * 
            ((timeB1 + minmiddle1) ^ (1 + x)))$minimum
      }, 
      shortA1 = shortA1, 
      middleA1 = middleA1, 
      timeA1 = timeA1,
      minshort1 = minshort1, 
      minmiddle1 = minmiddle1, 
      shortB1 = shortB1, 
      middleB1 = middleB1, 
      timeB1 = timeB1, ...)
}

df$seuil <-
  mapply(FUN = optime_f,
         shortA1 = df$shortA1,
         middleA1 = df$middleA1,
         timeA1 = df$timeA1,
         minshort1 = df$minshort1,
         minmiddle1 = df$minmiddle1,
         shortB1 = df$shortB1,
         middleB1 = df$middleB1,
         timeB1 = df$timeB1,
         MoreArgs = list(interval = c(-10000, 10000),
                         maximum = FALSE,
                         tol = 0.0001),
         SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems working (with few marginal corrections)! Only one last problem, the result is something like list(minimum = -9.99993911253388, objective = 1.18783700656077e-19) I think that I only need the objective (the minimum is a limit value, I have change the interval in (-10,10). How can I have only the objective value?

Comment: I made a small edit.  At the end of `optimize`, I added `$minimum`. This gets the minimum value out of the object to return the vector you're after.  So sorry I didn't think of that when I first wrote up the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last remark, why di I have result of the magnitude 10^-19, whereas tol=10^-4?

Comment: If 10^-20 was in the `minimum` result, that it is the value of `x` that best solves your equation given the other values.  It is effectively the same as 0. The tolerance is used in a different manner, `optimize` couldn't find another value to solve `x` that was smaller than `10^-20` using a tolerance of `10^-4`.  In other words, if `optimize` found two possible solutions of 10^-19 and 10^-15, the difference is less than the tolerance and `optimize` will consider those two results to be the same value.  In this case, I'm not sure which one it chooses as the "optimal" value.